# How to disable elements at background when preloader is running in Framework7 mobile App

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

I have mobile app where user can send message. I am showing preloader as Sending... when user clicks on send button. At the same time I want to make all background elements disable so that user will not able to click again until first message is delivered. I can do with Jquery to disable on beforeSend and enable it in success event of ajax.
But I have more than 4 buttons on form and there are multiple such forms.
I want to disable it when preloader is running on screen.
Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the modal indicator or preloader modal, it already disables the background view for you until your actions are done:

http://framework7.io/docs/modal.html#preloader-modal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make them unclickable when preloader is running:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

or from xml:

```
android:enabled="false"
```